# How to use an older version of glibc, for Python script to work on REHL 3, using PyInstaller on CentOS6

Tags: python, linux, rhel, pyinstaller

I have a RHEL3 server with Python 2.2! I need to run some scripts on that machine using 2.6 Python.

So I also have a CentOS 6 with Python 2.6. I wrote the code and used PyInstaller to give me a single executable. That works on the CentOS machine.

However, on the REHL3 I get this error

```
" /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found 
 /lib/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3.4' not found "
```

Understandable, as it's old vs new.

I tried using PyInstaller on CentOS 3 but there were dependencies and yum doesn't work and generally CentOS 3 is dead.

I thought I could install GLIBC 2.4 and 2.3.4 on CentOS 6 in a different directory. That could work, but I wouldn't know how to use PyInstaller to use that library.

Then I thought, could I chroot?

What are your ideas on this, as I am out of them!

Comment: It sounds like it'll be easier to just take the script but if you do manage to install glibc in a different directory you could do `LD_LIBARY_PATH=/path/to/new/glibc ./pyexec`

Answer (score 0):

I would search for that in repo. If there aren't, try to compile old version. [Look for it here.](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/)